# RUID & EUID after exec()

Tags: linux, exec, fork

With `fork()` operation child process inherits attribute real and effective user Id's from parent process, how it behaves when `exec()` is performed ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Exec does not change any of them.   From the linux manual :

> The exec() family of functions replaces the current process image with a new process image.

The *exec* changes the process image (the code and data segment in memory), but it does not change the process descriptor of the new process created with fork. The process descriptor contains the real and effective id, because this is not changed by an *exec* call, the effective and real id are not changed neither.

I hope that I have been clear explaining the concept.

The real and effective UID and GID of the child process are equal to the real and effective UID and GID of the parent process. Therefore, when the child process calls *exec* those values are not modified.

In order to prove this I wrote a small application that creates a child process which calls *exec*. The *exec* system call runs an application that prints out the value of the GID and UID of the current process. In addition the GID and UID of the parent process are showen as well, so that we can compare them.

**main.c**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 


void print_info () {

  printf("     UID           GID  \n"
        "Real      %d  Real      %d  \n"
        "Effective %d  Effective %d  \n",
             getuid (),     getgid (),
             geteuid(),     getegid()
    );
 return; 
}


int main () {

 pid_t pid; 
 int status; 
 pid = fork(); 

 if (!pid) {
   puts("Childe process\n"); 
   execv("./uid.out", NULL); 
   return;
 } 

 wait(status); 

 printf("Father %d -------------------\n", getpid());
 print_info();
 puts("--------------------------------"); 

 return 0; 
}
```

**uid.c**

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <unistd.h> 

int main () {

  printf("CHILD  %d -------------------\n", getpid()); 
  printf("     UID           GID  \n"
        "Real      %d  Real      %d  \n"
        "Effective %d  Effective %d  \n",
             getuid (),     getgid (),
             geteuid(),     getegid()
    );
  puts("---------------------------------");
 return 0; 
}
```

**Output :**

```
CHILD  17436 -------------------
     UID           GID  
Real      1000  Real      1000  
Effective 1000  Effective 1000  
---------------------------------
Father 17435 -------------------
     UID           GID  
Real      1000  Real      1000  
Effective 1000  Effective 1000  
--------------------------------
```

Let me know if you need more info.

Comment: I would like to know what actually happens to RUID and EUID after `exec()` is executed, meaning user Id's will be inherited and same or they are different before and after execution.

Comment: They are the same! I improved my answer, I hope I have been useful.